# Remove duplicates in foreach

Tags: php

I'm working with my code which displays all the folders and subfolders in my directory.

I have a simple problem.. some result are duplicates or repeated and I don't want to display it.

How can i do this?

```
<?php
    $dir = 'apps/';
    $result = array();

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
            foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file) {                    
                if (!$file->isFile()) {
                    $result = $file->getPath()."<br>";
                    echo $result;
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $dir = 'apps/';
    $result = array();

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
            foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file) {                    
                if (!$file->isFile()) {
                    $path = $file->getPath();
                    if(in_array($path, $result))  {
                        continue ;
                    }
                    $result = $path."<br>";
                    echo $result;
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: There are still duplicates

Comment: it could be due to whitespace in the file path, you can trim the path before checking it in the result array

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash array for checking if path already in list

```
<?php
    $dir = 'apps/';
    $result = array();
    $hash=array();

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
            foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file) {                    
                if (!$file->isFile()) {
                    $path = $file->getPath();
                    if(isset($hash[$path]))  {
                        continue ;
                    }
                     $hash[$path]=1;
                    $result[] = $path;
                    echo $path."<br>";
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_unique()`

```
<?php

$dir = 'apps/';
$result = array();

if(is_dir($dir)){

    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file){
        if(!$file->isFile()){
            $result[] = $file->getPath();
        }
    }

    $uniqueResult = array_unique($result);
    if(!empty($uniqueResult)){
        foreach($uniqueResult as $v){ // don't use 'for' use 'foreach' here.
            echo $v.'<br>';
        }
    }

}
```